# Is this simplification correct?

Tags: integration, inequality, integral-inequality

Let's have integral

$$
\tag 1 I = \int\limits_{x_0}^x dy \, g(y)A(y)
$$
Here $g(y)$ is positive monotonically decreased function, while $A$ is a positive definite function with $\int\limits_{x_0}^\infty A \, dx < \infty$.

May I estimate $(1)$ as
$$
I \leqslant g(x_0)\int\limits_{x_0}^x A(y) \, dy
$$

Answer (score 0):

Provided all the integrals are well defined, I see no problem arguing that if $g(y) \leqslant g(x_0) \ \forall y \in [x_0,x)$ then
$$
\int_{x_0}^x A(y) g(y) dy
    \leqslant \int_{x_0}^x A(y) g(x_0) dy
    = g(x_0) \int_{x_0}^x A(y) dy
$$